# how to convert json file data to string in bash shell script?

Tags: json, linux, bash

how to convert json file data to string in bash shell script?
i have below petstore swagger file (https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)
in json format.

i have converted this json file into string with backspaces characters \ needed for one operation using this site https://jsontostring.com/ .

i have tried jq tool to achieve this, didn't got the result and perhaps it will not come using jq tool.

How can we convert this same petstore swagger json file into string with below expected output in linux or bash shell script ?

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"description":"This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.","version":"1.0.6","title":"Swagger Petstore","termsOfService":"http://swagger.io/terms/","contact":{"email":"apiteam@swagger.io"},"license":{"name":"Apache 2.0","url":"http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"}},"host":"petstore.swagger.io","basePath":"/v2","tags":[{"name":"pet","description":"Everything about your Pets","externalDocs":{"description":"Find out more","url":"http://swagger.io"}},{"name":"store","description":"Access to Petstore orders"},{"name":"user","description":"Operations about user","externalDocs":{"description":"Find out more about our store","url":"http://swagger.io"}}],"schemes":["https","http"],"paths":{"/pet/{petId}/uploadImage":{"post":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"uploads an image","description":"","operationId":"uploadFile","consumes":["multipart/form-data"],"produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[{"name":"petId","in":"path","description":"ID of pet to update","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int64"},{"name":"additionalMetadata","in":"formData","description":"Additional data to pass to server","required":false,"type":"string"},{"name":"file","in":"formData","description":"file to upload","required":false,"type":"file"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/ApiResponse"}}},"security":[{"petstore_auth":["write:pets","read:pets"]}]}},"/pet":{"post":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"Add a new pet to the store","description":"","operationId":"addPet","consumes":["application/json","application/xml"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"in":"body","name":"body","description":"Pet object that needs to be added to the store","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"}}],"responses":{"405":{"description":"Invalid input"}},"security":[{"petstore_auth":["write:pets","read:pets"]}]},"put":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"Update an existing pet","description":"","operationId":"updatePet","consumes":["application/json","application/xml"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"in":"body","name":"body","description":"Pet object that needs to be added to the store","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"}}],"responses":{"400":{"description":"Invalid ID supplied"},"404":{"description":"Pet not found"},"405":{"description":"Validation exception"}},"security":[{"petstore_auth":["write:pets","read:pets"]}]}},"/pet/findByStatus":{"get":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"Finds Pets by status","description":"Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings","operationId":"findPetsByStatus","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"status","in":"query","description":"Status values that need to be considered for filter","required":true,"type":"array","items":{"type":"string","enum":["available","pending","sold"],"default":"available"},"collectionFormat":"multi"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"}}},"400":{"description":"Invalid status value"}},"security":[{"petstore_auth":["write:pets","read:pets"]}]}},"/pet/findByTags":{"get":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"Finds Pets by tags","description":"Multiple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.","operationId":"findPetsByTags","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"tags","in":"query","description":"Tags to filter by","required":true,"type":"array","items":{"type":"string"},"collectionFormat":"multi"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"}}},"400":{"description":"Invalid tag value"}},"security":[{"petstore_auth":["write:pets","read:pets"]}],"deprecated":true}},"/pet/{petId}":{"get":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"Find pet by ID","description":"Returns a single pet","operationId":"getPetById","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"petId","in":"path","description":"ID of pet to return","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int64"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"}},"400":{"description":"Invalid ID supplied"},"404":{"description":"Pet not found"}},"security":[{"api_key":[]}]},"post":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"Updates a pet in the store with form data","description":"","operationId":"updatePetWithForm","consumes":["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"petId","in":"path","description":"ID of pet that needs to be updated","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int64"},{"name":"name","in":"formData","description":"Updated name of the pet","required":false,"type":"string"},{"name":"status","in":"formData","description":"Updated status of the pet","required":false,"type":"string"}],"responses":{"405":{"description":"Invalid input"}},"security":[{"petstore_auth":["write:pets","read:pets"]}]},"delete":{"tags":["pet"],"summary":"Deletes a pet","description":"","operationId":"deletePet","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"api_key","in":"header","required":false,"type":"string"},{"name":"petId","in":"path","description":"Pet id to delete","required":true,"type":"integer","format":"int64"}],"responses":{"400":{"description":"Invalid ID supplied"},"404":{"description":"Pet not found"}},"security":[{"petstore_auth":["write:pets","read:pets"]}]}},"/store/order":{"post":{"tags":["store"],"summary":"Place an order for a pet","description":"","operationId":"placeOrder","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"in":"body","name":"body","description":"order placed for purchasing the pet","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Order"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Order"}},"400":{"description":"Invalid Order"}}}},"/store/order/{orderId}":{"get":{"tags":["store"],"summary":"Find purchase order by ID","description":"For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10. Other values will generated exceptions","operationId":"getOrderById","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"orderId","in":"path","description":"ID of pet that needs to be fetched","required":true,"type":"integer","maximum":10,"minimum":1,"format":"int64"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Order"}},"400":{"description":"Invalid ID supplied"},"404":{"description":"Order not found"}}},"delete":{"tags":["store"],"summary":"Delete purchase order by ID","description":"For valid response try integer IDs with positive integer value. Negative or non-integer values will generate API errors","operationId":"deleteOrder","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"orderId","in":"path","description":"ID of the order that needs to be deleted","required":true,"type":"integer","minimum":1,"format":"int64"}],"responses":{"400":{"description":"Invalid ID supplied"},"404":{"description":"Order not found"}}}},"/store/inventory":{"get":{"tags":["store"],"summary":"Returns pet inventories by status","description":"Returns a map of status codes to quantities","operationId":"getInventory","produces":["application/json"],"parameters":[],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"type":"object","additionalProperties":{"type":"integer","format":"int32"}}}},"security":[{"api_key":[]}]}},"/user/createWithArray":{"post":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Creates list of users with given input array","description":"","operationId":"createUsersWithArrayInput","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"in":"body","name":"body","description":"List of user object","required":true,"schema":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/User"}}}],"responses":{"default":{"description":"successful operation"}}}},"/user/createWithList":{"post":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Creates list of users with given input array","description":"","operationId":"createUsersWithListInput","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"in":"body","name":"body","description":"List of user object","required":true,"schema":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/User"}}}],"responses":{"default":{"description":"successful operation"}}}},"/user/{username}":{"get":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Get user by user name","description":"","operationId":"getUserByName","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"username","in":"path","description":"The name that needs to be fetched. Use user1 for testing. ","required":true,"type":"string"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/User"}},"400":{"description":"Invalid username supplied"},"404":{"description":"User not found"}}},"put":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Updated user","description":"This can only be done by the logged in user.","operationId":"updateUser","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"username","in":"path","description":"name that need to be updated","required":true,"type":"string"},{"in":"body","name":"body","description":"Updated user object","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/User"}}],"responses":{"400":{"description":"Invalid user supplied"},"404":{"description":"User not found"}}},"delete":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Delete user","description":"This can only be done by the logged in user.","operationId":"deleteUser","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"username","in":"path","description":"The name that needs to be deleted","required":true,"type":"string"}],"responses":{"400":{"description":"Invalid username supplied"},"404":{"description":"User not found"}}}},"/user/login":{"get":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Logs user into the system","description":"","operationId":"loginUser","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"name":"username","in":"query","description":"The user name for login","required":true,"type":"string"},{"name":"password","in":"query","description":"The password for login in clear text","required":true,"type":"string"}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"successful operation","headers":{"X-Expires-After":{"type":"string","format":"date-time","description":"date in UTC when token expires"},"X-Rate-Limit":{"type":"integer","format":"int32","description":"calls per hour allowed by the user"}},"schema":{"type":"string"}},"400":{"description":"Invalid username/password supplied"}}}},"/user/logout":{"get":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Logs out current logged in user session","description":"","operationId":"logoutUser","produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[],"responses":{"default":{"description":"successful operation"}}}},"/user":{"post":{"tags":["user"],"summary":"Create user","description":"This can only be done by the logged in user.","operationId":"createUser","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["application/json","application/xml"],"parameters":[{"in":"body","name":"body","description":"Created user object","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/User"}}],"responses":{"default":{"description":"successful operation"}}}}},"securityDefinitions":{"api_key":{"type":"apiKey","name":"api_key","in":"header"},"petstore_auth":{"type":"oauth2","authorizationUrl":"https://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/authorize","flow":"implicit","scopes":{"read:pets":"read your pets","write:pets":"modify pets in your account"}}},"definitions":{"ApiResponse":{"type":"object","properties":{"code":{"type":"integer","format":"int32"},"type":{"type":"string"},"message":{"type":"string"}}},"Category":{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},"name":{"type":"string"}},"xml":{"name":"Category"}},"Pet":{"type":"object","required":["name","photoUrls"],"properties":{"id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},"category":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Category"},"name":{"type":"string","example":"doggie"},"photoUrls":{"type":"array","xml":{"wrapped":true},"items":{"type":"string","xml":{"name":"photoUrl"}}},"tags":{"type":"array","xml":{"wrapped":true},"items":{"xml":{"name":"tag"},"$ref":"#/definitions/Tag"}},"status":{"type":"string","description":"pet status in the store","enum":["available","pending","sold"]}},"xml":{"name":"Pet"}},"Tag":{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},"name":{"type":"string"}},"xml":{"name":"Tag"}},"Order":{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},"petId":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},"quantity":{"type":"integer","format":"int32"},"shipDate":{"type":"string","format":"date-time"},"status":{"type":"string","description":"Order Status","enum":["placed","approved","delivered"]},"complete":{"type":"boolean"}},"xml":{"name":"Order"}},"User":{"type":"object","properties":{"id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64"},"username":{"type":"string"},"firstName":{"type":"string"},"lastName":{"type":"string"},"email":{"type":"string"},"password":{"type":"string"},"phone":{"type":"string"},"userStatus":{"type":"integer","format":"int32","description":"User Status"}},"xml":{"name":"User"}}},"externalDocs":{"description":"Find out more about Swagger","url":"http://swagger.io"}}
```

expected output;

```
"{\"swagger\":\"2.0\",\"info\":{\"description\":\"ThisisasampleserverPetstoreserver.YoucanfindoutmoreaboutSwaggerat[http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io)oron[irc.freenode.net,#swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).Forthissample,youcanusetheapikey`special-key`totesttheauthorizationfilters.\",\"version\":\"1.0.6\",\"title\":\"SwaggerPetstore\",\"termsOfService\":\"http://swagger.io/terms/\",\"contact\":{\"email\":\"apiteam@swagger.io\"},\"license\":{\"name\":\"Apache2.0\",\"url\":\"http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html\"}},\"host\":\"petstore.swagger.io\",\"basePath\":\"/v2\",\"tags\":[{\"name\":\"pet\",\"description\":\"EverythingaboutyourPets\",\"externalDocs\":{\"description\":\"Findoutmore\",\"url\":\"http://swagger.io\"}},{\"name\":\"store\",\"description\":\"AccesstoPetstoreorders\"},{\"name\":\"user\",\"description\":\"Operationsaboutuser\",\"externalDocs\":{\"description\":\"Findoutmoreaboutourstore\",\"url\":\"http://swagger.io\"}}],\"schemes\":[\"https\",\"http\"],\"paths\":{\"/pet/{petId}/uploadImage\":{\"post\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"uploadsanimage\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"uploadFile\",\"consumes\":[\"multipart/form-data\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"petId\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"IDofpettoupdate\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},{\"name\":\"additionalMetadata\",\"in\":\"formData\",\"description\":\"Additionaldatatopasstoserver\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"file\",\"in\":\"formData\",\"description\":\"filetoupload\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"file\"}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/ApiResponse\"}}},\"security\":[{\"petstore_auth\":[\"write:pets\",\"read:pets\"]}]}},\"/pet\":{\"post\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"Addanewpettothestore\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"addPet\",\"consumes\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"in\":\"body\",\"name\":\"body\",\"description\":\"Petobjectthatneedstobeaddedtothestore\",\"required\":true,\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Pet\"}}],\"responses\":{\"405\":{\"description\":\"Invalidinput\"}},\"security\":[{\"petstore_auth\":[\"write:pets\",\"read:pets\"]}]},\"put\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"Updateanexistingpet\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"updatePet\",\"consumes\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"in\":\"body\",\"name\":\"body\",\"description\":\"Petobjectthatneedstobeaddedtothestore\",\"required\":true,\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Pet\"}}],\"responses\":{\"400\":{\"description\":\"InvalidIDsupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Petnotfound\"},\"405\":{\"description\":\"Validationexception\"}},\"security\":[{\"petstore_auth\":[\"write:pets\",\"read:pets\"]}]}},\"/pet/findByStatus\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"FindsPetsbystatus\",\"description\":\"Multiplestatusvaluescanbeprovidedwithcommaseparatedstrings\",\"operationId\":\"findPetsByStatus\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"status\",\"in\":\"query\",\"description\":\"Statusvaluesthatneedtobeconsideredforfilter\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"enum\":[\"available\",\"pending\",\"sold\"],\"default\":\"available\"},\"collectionFormat\":\"multi\"}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Pet\"}}},\"400\":{\"description\":\"Invalidstatusvalue\"}},\"security\":[{\"petstore_auth\":[\"write:pets\",\"read:pets\"]}]}},\"/pet/findByTags\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"FindsPetsbytags\",\"description\":\"Multipletagscanbeprovidedwithcommaseparatedstrings.Usetag1,tag2,tag3fortesting.\",\"operationId\":\"findPetsByTags\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"tags\",\"in\":\"query\",\"description\":\"Tagstofilterby\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"collectionFormat\":\"multi\"}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Pet\"}}},\"400\":{\"description\":\"Invalidtagvalue\"}},\"security\":[{\"petstore_auth\":[\"write:pets\",\"read:pets\"]}],\"deprecated\":true}},\"/pet/{petId}\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"FindpetbyID\",\"description\":\"Returnsasinglepet\",\"operationId\":\"getPetById\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"petId\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"IDofpettoreturn\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Pet\"}},\"400\":{\"description\":\"InvalidIDsupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Petnotfound\"}},\"security\":[{\"api_key\":[]}]},\"post\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"Updatesapetinthestorewithformdata\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"updatePetWithForm\",\"consumes\":[\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"petId\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"IDofpetthatneedstobeupdated\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"in\":\"formData\",\"description\":\"Updatednameofthepet\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"status\",\"in\":\"formData\",\"description\":\"Updatedstatusofthepet\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"string\"}],\"responses\":{\"405\":{\"description\":\"Invalidinput\"}},\"security\":[{\"petstore_auth\":[\"write:pets\",\"read:pets\"]}]},\"delete\":{\"tags\":[\"pet\"],\"summary\":\"Deletesapet\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"deletePet\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"api_key\",\"in\":\"header\",\"required\":false,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"petId\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"Petidtodelete\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"}],\"responses\":{\"400\":{\"description\":\"InvalidIDsupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Petnotfound\"}},\"security\":[{\"petstore_auth\":[\"write:pets\",\"read:pets\"]}]}},\"/store/order\":{\"post\":{\"tags\":[\"store\"],\"summary\":\"Placeanorderforapet\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"placeOrder\",\"consumes\":[\"application/json\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"in\":\"body\",\"name\":\"body\",\"description\":\"orderplacedforpurchasingthepet\",\"required\":true,\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Order\"}}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Order\"}},\"400\":{\"description\":\"InvalidOrder\"}}}},\"/store/order/{orderId}\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"store\"],\"summary\":\"FindpurchaseorderbyID\",\"description\":\"ForvalidresponsetryintegerIDswithvalue>=1and<=10.Othervalueswillgeneratedexceptions\",\"operationId\":\"getOrderById\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"orderId\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"IDofpetthatneedstobefetched\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"integer\",\"maximum\":10,\"minimum\":1,\"format\":\"int64\"}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Order\"}},\"400\":{\"description\":\"InvalidIDsupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Ordernotfound\"}}},\"delete\":{\"tags\":[\"store\"],\"summary\":\"DeletepurchaseorderbyID\",\"description\":\"ForvalidresponsetryintegerIDswithpositiveintegervalue.Negativeornon-integervalueswillgenerateAPIerrors\",\"operationId\":\"deleteOrder\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"orderId\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"IDoftheorderthatneedstobedeleted\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"integer\",\"minimum\":1,\"format\":\"int64\"}],\"responses\":{\"400\":{\"description\":\"InvalidIDsupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Ordernotfound\"}}}},\"/store/inventory\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"store\"],\"summary\":\"Returnspetinventoriesbystatus\",\"description\":\"Returnsamapofstatuscodestoquantities\",\"operationId\":\"getInventory\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\"],\"parameters\":[],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"additionalProperties\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int32\"}}}},\"security\":[{\"api_key\":[]}]}},\"/user/createWithArray\":{\"post\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Createslistofuserswithgiveninputarray\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"createUsersWithArrayInput\",\"consumes\":[\"application/json\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"in\":\"body\",\"name\":\"body\",\"description\":\"Listofuserobject\",\"required\":true,\"schema\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/User\"}}}],\"responses\":{\"default\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\"}}}},\"/user/createWithList\":{\"post\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Createslistofuserswithgiveninputarray\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"createUsersWithListInput\",\"consumes\":[\"application/json\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"in\":\"body\",\"name\":\"body\",\"description\":\"Listofuserobject\",\"required\":true,\"schema\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/User\"}}}],\"responses\":{\"default\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\"}}}},\"/user/{username}\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Getuserbyusername\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"getUserByName\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"username\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"Thenamethatneedstobefetched.Useuser1fortesting.\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"string\"}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/User\"}},\"400\":{\"description\":\"Invalidusernamesupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Usernotfound\"}}},\"put\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Updateduser\",\"description\":\"Thiscanonlybedonebytheloggedinuser.\",\"operationId\":\"updateUser\",\"consumes\":[\"application/json\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"username\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"namethatneedtobeupdated\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"in\":\"body\",\"name\":\"body\",\"description\":\"Updateduserobject\",\"required\":true,\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/User\"}}],\"responses\":{\"400\":{\"description\":\"Invalidusersupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Usernotfound\"}}},\"delete\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Deleteuser\",\"description\":\"Thiscanonlybedonebytheloggedinuser.\",\"operationId\":\"deleteUser\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"username\",\"in\":\"path\",\"description\":\"Thenamethatneedstobedeleted\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"string\"}],\"responses\":{\"400\":{\"description\":\"Invalidusernamesupplied\"},\"404\":{\"description\":\"Usernotfound\"}}}},\"/user/login\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Logsuserintothesystem\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"loginUser\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"username\",\"in\":\"query\",\"description\":\"Theusernameforlogin\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"password\",\"in\":\"query\",\"description\":\"Thepasswordforloginincleartext\",\"required\":true,\"type\":\"string\"}],\"responses\":{\"200\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\",\"headers\":{\"X-Expires-After\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"format\":\"date-time\",\"description\":\"dateinUTCwhentokenexpires\"},\"X-Rate-Limit\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int32\",\"description\":\"callsperhourallowedbytheuser\"}},\"schema\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"400\":{\"description\":\"Invalidusername/passwordsupplied\"}}}},\"/user/logout\":{\"get\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Logsoutcurrentloggedinusersession\",\"description\":\"\",\"operationId\":\"logoutUser\",\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[],\"responses\":{\"default\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\"}}}},\"/user\":{\"post\":{\"tags\":[\"user\"],\"summary\":\"Createuser\",\"description\":\"Thiscanonlybedonebytheloggedinuser.\",\"operationId\":\"createUser\",\"consumes\":[\"application/json\"],\"produces\":[\"application/json\",\"application/xml\"],\"parameters\":[{\"in\":\"body\",\"name\":\"body\",\"description\":\"Createduserobject\",\"required\":true,\"schema\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/User\"}}],\"responses\":{\"default\":{\"description\":\"successfuloperation\"}}}}},\"securityDefinitions\":{\"api_key\":{\"type\":\"apiKey\",\"name\":\"api_key\",\"in\":\"header\"},\"petstore_auth\":{\"type\":\"oauth2\",\"authorizationUrl\":\"https://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/authorize\",\"flow\":\"implicit\",\"scopes\":{\"read:pets\":\"readyourpets\",\"write:pets\":\"modifypetsinyouraccount\"}}},\"definitions\":{\"ApiResponse\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"code\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int32\"},\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"message\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}},\"Category\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"xml\":{\"name\":\"Category\"}},\"Pet\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"required\":[\"name\",\"photoUrls\"],\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},\"category\":{\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Category\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"example\":\"doggie\"},\"photoUrls\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"xml\":{\"wrapped\":true},\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"xml\":{\"name\":\"photoUrl\"}}},\"tags\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"xml\":{\"wrapped\":true},\"items\":{\"xml\":{\"name\":\"tag\"},\"$ref\":\"#/definitions/Tag\"}},\"status\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"description\":\"petstatusinthestore\",\"enum\":[\"available\",\"pending\",\"sold\"]}},\"xml\":{\"name\":\"Pet\"}},\"Tag\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"xml\":{\"name\":\"Tag\"}},\"Order\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},\"petId\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},\"quantity\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int32\"},\"shipDate\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"format\":\"date-time\"},\"status\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"description\":\"OrderStatus\",\"enum\":[\"placed\",\"approved\",\"delivered\"]},\"complete\":{\"type\":\"boolean\"}},\"xml\":{\"name\":\"Order\"}},\"User\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int64\"},\"username\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"firstName\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"lastName\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"email\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"password\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"phone\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"userStatus\":{\"type\":\"integer\",\"format\":\"int32\",\"description\":\"UserStatus\"}},\"xml\":{\"name\":\"User\"}}},\"externalDocs\":{\"description\":\"FindoutmoreaboutSwagger\",\"url\":\"http://swagger.io\"}}"
```

Comment: How/from where do you get your JSON? What do you want to do with this string? Why do you need to encode a JSON object as a single string? This smells XY problem and probably no conversion is required.

Answer (score 5):

Just like [@ibrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9410412/ibrahim-tanyalcin) suggested, you can combine `jq -R` with `jq -c` so a json file can be easily converted to a string with this:

```
cat file.json | jq -c | jq -R
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: cool command...

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

J=$(curl -k https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)
Q=${J//\"/\\\"}  # see pattern substitution in 'man bash'
echo \""$Q"\" #double quote variable, shellcheck
```

Comment: getting the below comment error message from the server I'm trying to pass this data.                                      J=$(curl -k https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)
Q=${J//\"/\\\"}                                                                                                                      echo \"$Q\"

Comment: {"timestamp":"2022-12-03T13:10:21.636+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 101] (through reference chain: com.demo.dxt.dto.project.Project[\"openText\"])","path":"/api/v1/projects"}

Comment: while when I use the output data from this website https://jsontostring.com/ it passes successfully, without any errors. Can't tell what's main difference  between the two outputs.

Comment: I would suggest using a json beautifier(just google it) to reformat the json to make it more human-readable. There seems to be a problem with one of the fields. Does it have to be one line?

Comment: @devops-admin The quoting in that `curl` command is all messed up; neither of the variable references are actually in double-quotes, so the shell's going to parse them in unpleasant ways before passing them to `curl`. As usual, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out the problems. And until you fix that, there's no point in worrying about formatting the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`cat whatever.json | jq -R`

`-R` is for `--raw-input`.

PS: You can get `jq` by `sudo apt-get install jq`

Comment: I had to .dot to store the result in a variable                                                                                     openText=$(cat whatever.json | jq . -R)                                                                                      but still getting the error message like the below comment error message.

Comment: {"timestamp":"2022-12-03T13:46:22.686+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 101] (through reference chain: com.demo.dxt.dto.project.Project[\"openText\"])","path":"/api/v1/projects"}

Comment: here's the complete post request.                                                                                                               curl -s  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --location --request POST "https://example.com/api/v1/projects" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" -d  '{"name":"'${PROJECT_NAME}'","openText":'${openText}',"personalizedCoverage":{"auths":[]}}'

Comment: Does your API return the stringified JSON, if yes remove the intermediate step of using jsontostring.com. Jq will give an error if you pass an escaped json.

Comment: json string conversion was perfect. it was failing in our application because of whitespaces characters. So after adding the below lines it passes successfully.                                openText=$(cat whatever.json | jq . -R |  sed 's/ //g')